# different handles in public static final class variable

Tags: java

I have clas that emulates enum behavior for java 1.4

```
public class PacketType {

    String Name ="9";

    public static final PacketType None = new PacketType("9");
    public static final PacketType StartOfOperation = new PacketType("1");

    PacketType (String Name ) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Name ;       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PacketType p = PacketType.StartOfOperation;

        if (p == PacketType.StartOfOperation) {
            System.out.print("==");
        }

        if (p.equals(PacketType.StartOfOperation) ) {
            System.out.print("equals");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to know which value has variable `p`. Both , `equals` and `==` pass checking in the main function. But in case I have several threads in my application it does't pass this check.  I have assigned the same static variable `PacketType.StartOfOperation` for all my `PacketType` variables. Debugger shows that I have the same value, but not the same variable handler (that is why it not pass `equal` and `==`). I expect that it should have the same handle. Why it behaves so strange?

Comment: Can you show example code that fails?

Comment: You're checking equality of PacketType.None and PacketType.StartOfOperation in the above code...

Comment: What output do you get when you run this?

Comment: Any specific reason you're not using simply `public static final int`?

Comment: Show us your real code, the output you get, and the output you expect. Without seeing it, we can only guess. And read the javadoc for `Object.equals()`

Comment: to JB Nizet. I know why equals not works in my case. This because java has created another instance on PacketType. But why JVM did so?

Comment: @user1501700 I think it is red herring. The code above doesn't have such problems. Maybe you have something else with your multithreading, please show more code. Maybe it is a web app with several class loaders?

Comment: I can't post whole code because it is too big. I have solved this problem by overriding equals() method that checks strings Name content

Answer (score 0):

When you use `==` it returns true if both references point to same object.

```
if (p == PacketType.StartOfOperation)
```

Here both the references points to different objects, hence it will not execute. Try this

```
 PacketType p =PacketType.None;
 PacketType p1 =PacketType.None;   

    if (p == p1)
    {
    System.out.print("=="); //prints ==
    }
```

Since None is static, every reference points to same object and `==` will return true.